# fwrite() on windows server

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using fopen and fwrite to create a video. When I am testing it works on my laptop when I tried to transfer the file on our windows server fopen and fwrite suddenly stops working. We are using windows server 2012. What can I do to fix this?

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

$CAFNo = $json_obj->CAFNo;
$Date = $json_obj->CAFDate;
$Video = $json_obj->Video;
$CafDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Date));

$video_decode = base64_decode($Video);
$video_filename = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/TBSApp/uploads/'. $CAFNo . '_'.$CafDate.'_VID.mp4';

$handle = fopen($video_filename, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $video_decode);
fclose($handle);

$video_dbfilename = './uploads/'. $CAFNo . '_'.$CafDate.'_VID.mp4';
if(file_exists($video_filename)) {
   $temp_video_filename = __DIR__ . '/tmp/'. $CAFNo . '_'.$CafDate.'_VID.mp4';
   exec('ffmpeg -i '.$video_filename.' -c:v libx264 '.$temp_video_filename.' 2>&1');
   unlink($video_filename);
   rename($temp_video_filename, $video_filename);
}

$sql = "UPDATE tblCaf SET Video = '$video_dbfilename' WHERE CAFNo = '$CAFNo'";
mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and you should see the warning message about why it's failing. My guess is it's a permissions problem.

Comment: @Barmar do I just add error_reporting(E_ALL)? Where do I see the error?

Comment: You'll see the error wherever the output of the script is shown.

Comment: This is basic debugging, a PHP web programmer should do this routinely.

Comment: @Barmar how can I check the error I am getting an JSON

Comment: Use the Network tab of the Developer Tools and look in the Reponse data.

Comment: ... or just enable/read error logs

Comment: @user1597430 where do I enable that?

Comment: php.ini of course

Comment: @user1597430 error logs are enabled but the folder for error logs is missing

Comment: Do you ask my permission to create it? Don't forget to restart a web server after it.

Comment: @I think not how can I create it?